# Задержка в each

Tags: javascript, jquery

как сделать задержку на переход к следующему элементу и событие submit? 
есть формы у товара с разными размерами

```
<div class="box-size">
        <form method="post" class="ms2_form">
            <div class="number">
                <label for="">XS/42</label>
                <div class="data-input">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="48">
                    <input type="hidden" name="options[size]" value="XS/42">
                    <input type="number" name="count" size="5" value="0">
                    <span class="plus">+</span>
                    <span class="minus">-</span>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add" style="display: none;"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
            <form method="post" class="ms2_form">
            <div class="number">
                <label for="">S/44</label>
                <div class="data-input">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="48">
                    <input type="hidden" name="options[size]" value="S/44">
                    <input type="number" name="count" size="5" value="0">
                    <span class="plus">+</span>
                    <span class="minus">-</span>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add" style="display: none;"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
            <form method="post" class="ms2_form">
            <div class="number">
                <label for="">M/46</label>
                <div class="data-input">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="48">
                    <input type="hidden" name="options[size]" value="M/46">
                    <input type="number" name="count" size="5" value="0">
                    <span class="plus">+</span>
                    <span class="minus">-</span>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add" style="display: none;"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
            <form method="post" class="ms2_form">
            <div class="number">
                <label for="">L/48</label>
                <div class="data-input">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="48">
                    <input type="hidden" name="options[size]" value="L/48">
                    <input type="number" name="count" size="5" value="0">
                    <span class="plus">+</span>
                    <span class="minus">-</span>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add" style="display: none;"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
            <form method="post" class="ms2_form">
            <div class="number">
                <label for="">XL/50</label>
                <div class="data-input">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="48">
                    <input type="hidden" name="options[size]" value="XL/50">
                    <input type="number" name="count" size="5" value="0">
                    <span class="plus">+</span>
                    <span class="minus">-</span>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add" style="display: none;"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

при клике на добавить должен скрипт обходить инпуты, и если, хоть идин из них пуст, то не добавлять

```
   $('.product-item .cart-btn').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.product-item').find('form.ms2_form').each(function(){
            if ($(this).find('input[name="count"]').val() > 0) { 
                $(this).submit();
             }
        });
    });
```

Comment: не использовать each

Comment: изменил вопрос,

Comment: эм... а причем тут задержка? Ты хочешь прервать обход если хотя бы один инпут пуст?

Comment: нет, вот так он из 5 размеров, добавляет 1 http://litesite.extremje.beget.tech/katalog/platya

Comment: тогда я не понимаю что именно ты спрашиваешь :-) вызов submit, в обычном случае, перезагрузит страницу. то есть сейчас как только ты находишь первый заполненный инпут - ты перезагружаешь страницу. Но что ты хочешь сделать - все еще непонятно.

Comment: идет ajax добавление товара, если выбрать все размеры, то он добавит только 2 из 5 например, я так понимаю ему нужна либо задержка либо не знаю что

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под _ajax добавление товара_? Что и куда в итоге добавляется?

Comment: вот на сайте я сделал  litesite.extremje.beget.tech/katalog/platya